# Load game data via ajax

Tags: ajax, impactjs

what are The Best practies To load game data that are Stored in a mysql database?

I'm using ajax request. But The async Call is a problem because i can't sync The game level with The data load. And game does Not start because the variable is  not defined. If i use sync Call, The loop wait The result And all the entities are blocked on The screen.

How Can i resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say sockets, TCP will work great if you don't aim to a MMO-thing.

If you just want to use AJAX calls, you can use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to trigger the callback (the game itself) once the data has been received.